# Logic statement not returning a variable, rather a value

Tags: java

```
(Math.random() > 0.75) ? type = TreeType.BIG_TREE : type = TreeType.TREE
```

How come (Math.random() > 0.75) returns a value, according to console, rather than a variable? The above statement is part of an if-else ladder.

Comment: What is your question? Are you getting any error?

Comment: Nothing in Java 'returns a variable'. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want the following

```
type = (Math.random() > 0.75) ? TreeType.BIG_TREE : TreeType.TREE
```

Comment: And yet `type = TreeType.BIG_TREE` still returns a value; what makes it different from another statement like `x + y`? The placement of `type` is not the full problem here.

Answer (score 2):

Good question. Actually what you have **could hypothetically work** if you make it a full statement. e.g.

```
TreeType tree = 
          (Math.random() > 0.75) ? (type = TreeType.BIG_TREE) : 
                                   (type = TreeType.TREE);
```

compiles fine (assuming you're assigning `type` to something of type `TreeType`, of course). Notice that all I did was add `TreeType tree =` (and add parenthesis to deal with the order of operations). This is because assignments actually return a value, specifically whatever the right-hand side evaluated to.

Obviously,

```
type = (Math.random() > 0.75) ? TreeType.BIG_TREE : TreeType.TREE
```

would be preferred as it is more terse and readable.

Answer (score 0):

According to: http://java.about.com/od/t/g/ternaryoperator.htm

> The first operand is a boolean expression; if the expression is true then the value of the second operand is returned otherwise the value of the third operand is returned.

I believe what you are seeing is that the value of type after the assignment is complete is returned. (I haven't done java in a while, but that's likely the case.) You should instead do:

```
type = (Math.random() > 0.75) ? TreeType.BIG_TREE : TreeType.TREE;
```